# How to include dependencies in a python build wheel file

Tags: python, dependencies, alpine-linux, python-packaging, alpine-package-keeper

I have a python app that I am trying to package for postmarketos via abuild. I got the abuild to create the package, but I have a single dependency that I must install with pip because the apk repositories do not contain this package. Does anyone know how to include the package in the python -m build or if apkbuild allows for postinstallation hooks.

I am very new to alpine linux and to python packaging.

Comment: I guess you should package and distribute the dependency separately. As its own *apk* (or whatever) maybe?